# Set my logo to the left and navigation menu to the right using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make a header with my name on the left and a navigator with "about" "portfolio" "contact" to the right using flexbox.

I am using `justify-content: flex-end;` in my flexbox container but the items doesn't justify to the right, they stay to the left and I don't know why.

I can use all kinds of `justify-content` but the header stays the same.

I want to know how I make the name "Roger Anderson" stays to the left and "About, portfolio, contact" to the right.

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
       v2.0 | 20110126
       License: none (public domain)
    */

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/* COMEÇADO O ESTILO */

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo-name,
.nav li {
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  align-self: center;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.logo {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
}

a:link {
  color: white;
}


/*
    ========================================
      Navigation
    ========================================
    */

.nav {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

< !DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Roger Anderson</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel" rel="stylesheet"></head><body>< !-- Header --><header class="primary-header"><h5 class="logo-name">Roger Anderson</h5><nav class="nav"><ul><li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>< !-- --><li><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>< !-- --><li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li></ul></nav></header></body></html>My CSS:
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
       v2.0 | 20110126
       License: none (public domain)
    */

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/* COMEÇADO O ESTILO */

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo-name,
.nav li {
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  align-self: center;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.logo {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
}

a:link {
  color: white;
}


/*
    ========================================
      Navigation
    ========================================
    */

.nav {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<header class="primary-header">

  <h5 class="logo-name">Roger Anderson</h5>

  <nav class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
      <!--
              -->
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>
      <!--
              -->
      <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this:

```
.nav {
  margin-right: auto;  
}
```

Instead use this:

```
.nav {
  margin-left: auto;  
}
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}



/* COMEÇADO O ESTILO */

header {
display:flex;   
justify-content: flex-end;
background-color: black;
height: 50px;
align-items:center;
width:100%;


}

.logo-name, .nav li {
font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
color: white;
font-weight: 400;    
text-transform: uppercase; 
align-self: center;
padding-left: 5px;    
}

.logo {
height: 25px;  
width: 25px;
}

a{text-decoration: none; }
a:visited {color: white;}
a:link {color: white;}

/*
========================================
  Navigation
========================================
*/

.nav {
 /* margin-right: auto;   */
 margin-left: auto; /* NEW */
}


.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;

}
```

```html
<header class="primary-header">
  <h5 class="logo-name">Roger Anderson</h5>
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Flex `auto` margins consume all free space in the direction of the margin.

So when you set `margin-right: auto` on the navigation menu, that consumes all free space on the right, pinning the menu to the left.

But if you use `margin-left: auto`, that consumes all free space on the left, pushing the menu away from the logo and pinning it to the right.

Here's a more complete explanation:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

---

There are two reasons why `justify-content` was not working:

1. Flex `auto` margins take precedence over keyword alignment properties (such as `justify-content` and `align-items`). If an `auto` margin is set, that gets the first shot and consumes all free space on the line. `justify-content` goes second, but there is no free space left, so it can't do anything.

   > [**8.1. Aligning with `auto`
   >   margins**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)
   >
   > Prior to alignment via `justify-content` and `align-self`, any
   >   positive free space is distributed to `auto` margins in that
   >   dimension.
   >
   > If free space is distributed to `auto` margins, the alignment
   >   properties will have no effect in that dimension because the margins
   >   will have stolen all free space left over after flexing.
2. Even if there was no `auto` margin, and `justify-content` was working, it wouldn't work as you expect because you have the value set to `flex-end`. This pins all items to the right. You would need to use `space-between` or `space-around`.

Comment: Amazing explanation, you are a great dude!

Answer (score 2):

```
     .primary-header {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include a short explanation of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Justify-content: flex-end; will justify both the header and the list items to the right. You want to use justify-content: space-between; instead. ([A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/))
2. You can use flexbox to position the list items beside each other. Just add display: flex; to .nav ul.
3. Remove display: inline-block; from the li elements and margin-right: auto; from .nav. Personally, I prefer to solve alignment purely by flexbox properties.

Example:

```
header {
  display: flex;   
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PeKXYw

Comment: Your explanation for why the items are pinned to the left is incorrect. Also, `margin-right: auto` on the `.nav` element is pure flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

**Simplified Version:**

`display: flex;` aligns the two divs side by side.

`margin-left: auto;` aligns the second div to the right.

`align-items: center;` aligns the contents vertically.

```css
/* Required Code */

#divNav {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

#divNavRight {
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* Extra Code */

#divNav {
  border: black solid 2px;
}

#divNav a {
  margin: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="divNav">
  <a href="/" style="font-size: 48px;">
    LOGO
  </a>
  <a href="/">LINK</a>
  <div id="divNavRight">
    <a href="/">LINK</a>
    <a href="/">LINK</a>
    <a href="/">LINK</a>
  </div>
</div>
```